How to make Neovim associate ".tpp" file extension with C++ files?
I would like Neovim to associate files with .tpp extension with C++.
How can I achieve this?
P.S.:
I would like nvim-lspconfig and nvim-cmp Neovim plugins to also associate
this file extension with C++.
I want to indicate that Neovim is writing me Unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in '' clang (fe_expected_compiler_job) [1, 1] after opening .tpp file. What could it mean?


:help new-filetype

You could use:
1. :h vim.filetype.add():
vim.filetype.add({
  extension = {
    tpp = "cpp",
  },
})

2. :h ftdetect
In nvim/after/ftdetect add a module with an autocmd to set the filetype accordly:
-- nvim/after/ftdetect/cpp.lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufRead", "BufNewFile" }, {
  group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("CustomCppDetection", {}),
  desc = "Set .ttp files to C++",
  callback = function(ev)
    if vim.fn.expand("%"):sub(-4) == ".tpp" then
      vim.api.nvim_set_option_value("filetype", "cpp", { buf = ev.buf })
    end
  end,
})

Full documentation on :h filetype
