Why does code completion not work for ".tpp" file extension in Neovim?
I have installed nvim-lspconfig and nvim-cmp plugins for Neovim. A code completion with ccls works pretty well for .cpp and .hpp file extensions. I want to make code completion to also work with .tpp file extension. I have created tpp.vim file inside ~/.config/nvim/ftdetect directory, which contains au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tpp set filetype=cpp Vim script. After doing this, syntax highlighting started to work for .tpp file, but code completion not.
vim.filetype.add({
        extension = {
                tpp = "cpp",
        },
})

I have also added these lines of code inside ~/.config/nvim/init.lua file, code completion still not wants to start working. So with all of that I have done - only syntax highlighting started to work for .tpp file extension, but code completion not. How can I make code completion to also start working for this file extension?
lspconfig: require("lspconfig.health").check()

LSP configs active in this session (globally) ~
- Configured servers: ccls
- OK Deprecated servers: (none)

LSP configs active in this buffer (bufnr: 1) ~
- Language client log: ~/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log
- Detected filetype: `cpp`
- 1 client(s) attached to this buffer
- Client: `ccls` (id: 1, bufnr: [1])
  root directory:    ~/TurboINI/
  filetypes:         c, cpp, objc, objcpp, cuda
  cmd:               /usr/local/bin/ccls
  version:           `Debian ccls version 0.20241108-2-g4331c895`
  executable:        true
  autostart:         true

Even tho LSP detected that this file's extension is related to C++, but code completion still not wants to work:
I assume that solution to this is hiding in ccls and not in Neovim plugins.
P.S. I have found an article on how to make a specific file extensions behave exactly like standard C++ extensions on vi.stackexchange.com, I have tried it out and ccls still not wants to do code completion. In principe code completion works, but as database it takes already what you have typed in a file, as an example if I typed #include <iostream> its database will only contain #include and <iostream> and nothing else.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79231569/how-to-make-neovim-associate-tpp-file-extension-with-c-files

@Someprogrammerdude not related

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

As @HighCommander4 mentioned on GitHub

.tpp is not a file extension that clang recognizes as a C++ file type.
You can nonetheless get clangd to process a .tpp file as C++ if you specify a -xc++ flag explicitly in the compile command (using, for example, a clangd config file).

To make code completion work for non-standard C++ file extension, I have to specify -xc++ argument to a compiler, e.g. g++ -xc++ or clang -xc++, because GCC and clang are not recognizing .tpp as C++ file extension.
So for clangd, in .clangd config file I have to add an -xc++ argument and it will look like this:
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-xc++]

And for ccls .ccls configuration file using GCC compiler it will look like this:
g++
-xc++

Hooray! Finally code completion for .tpp file started to work!
