Matching webcam image to list of 64x64 images
I'm trying to get a guitar pedal interfaced with a computer. This webMIDI interface almost works but doesn't know how to work with a few effects, and I'm trying to clean that up. My goal is to manually set an effect with the pedal's button, then over the USB interface ask the system for its info and record the effect-info pair. To save me from having to manually record what effect is selected, I'm using a webcam to take a picture of the effect on the pedal's screen so I can match it to one of the ~200 64x64 pictures in the above project's repository.
The problem is the image matching. I can take a pretty clear webcam image, crop it to this, and I've tried thresholding it; but I can't get python to match the right 64x64 image (upscaled 3x) to it. This example apparently matches Bass Squeak better than Comp
My code is

for file in files:
    features = 10
    
    img = cv2.imread(effect_image_folder + file, 0)
    scaled_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=1, fy=1, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    kp_effect, des_effect = orb.detectAndCompute(scaled_img, None)
    kp_pedal, des_pedal = orb.detectAndCompute(template_gray, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck = True)

    matches = bf.match(des_effect, des_pedal)

    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x:x.distance)
    # img3 = cv2.drawMatches(scaled_img, kp_effect, template_gray, kp_pedal, matches[:features], None, flags = cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
    # plt.imshow(img3)
    # plt.show()


    total_dist = 0
    for cv_match in matches[0:features]:
        total_dist = total_dist + cv_match.distance
    # print(total_dist)

    confidences = confidences + [total_dist]


and then whatever confidence is lowest is the winner. Anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this better? I'm new to CV so for all I know this is a bad algorithm for the task. I tried template matching at first but decided it was too sensitive to scaling and rotation, and likely other factors.

I can't figure out why all the links are broken on this post. If you want to edit it please feel free

The links aren't broken, they're just collected at the bottom of the post.

@TimRoberts true, but I wanted the links in the body, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79238198/why-does-code-completion-not-work-for-tpp-file-extension-in-neovim
Well, never mind, I fixed it

clear? looks blurry to me. and saturated. adjust exposure and focus of your camera.

and those thumbnails are also shrunk to hell. do not do that.

@ChristophRackwitz they're not my pictures, and I don't have control of exposure or focus. We're working with what we've got here

So you have a digital device, which can be controlled remotely, but your web GUI doesn’t know the device well enough. So instead of fixing the code, you think the best approach is to put a webcam on the device? And you some how expected that to be easy? And why wouldn’t you control your pictures? How come you can’t control the exposure and focus? How come you can’t record your own templates? This whole situation is mind-boggling.

@CrisLuengo It's not actually that complicated of a situation. Please reread my first paragraph. This image recognition is in service of fixing the code. I'm using a webcam so I can automate my testing, not a DSLR with nice optical zoom and focus. The point is to avoid manually recording data 200+ times.
The pictures are obviously "good enough" because, you, I, and chatGPT can tell which pictures match better. So, if you have knowledge on computer vision, the important part of the problem, that you can add, I'd welcome that

how many different pictures do you have to match against? if you had to do this all manually, how much time would that cost you? why can you not obtain better quality "templates" than 64 by 64? does that webcam not have a focus adjustment ring? does the picture get sharper if you move further away? can you switch on a lamp so the area surrounding the display isn't as dim? generally, you'd benefit from cooperating rather than frustrating. you're the one looking for help and on these tags there's a finite pool of people capable of solving such problems.

@ChristophRackwitz 225. If I gave up on automating the matching I estimate it'd take about 2 hours to do it manually. The templates are from the utility I linked; making better ones would also take me at least two hours. No focus ring on the webcam. I can move the device and wind up with a better image, and in fact have done that, and found I still wasn't getting good matching.

This feels like the classic stack overflow trope of "well, why are you trying to do A by working on x? You should be doing y instead." Indeed, y is typically better. But I'm asking about x, not A. There's context here that I alone have, and I'd prefer if people would trust that I'm asking about x for a reason, rather than telling me that there are better ways to do A. In this case, I have three images and want an algorithm that will correctly match the first to one of the other two. I feel like I'd be getting more helpful results if I had just eliminated all context, which is silly

@ChristophRackwitz though, if you meant how many webcam pictures am I matching against the 225, it's 1350

the classic stack overflow trope of "well, why are you trying to do A by working on x? You should be doing y instead." — This is not a trope, that is people trying to be helpful. We often see people try the wrong approach. I'd prefer if people would trust that I'm asking about x for a reason. I have helped a lot of people by questioning why they’re doing x. Some people have a good reason to do x, some people learned there is a better approach, and a very few times people become defensive.

[a very few times people become defensive.] This is one of those cases. It means you realize you’re likely doing something dumb but don’t want to be told about it. Good luck with your project! (Just know that a typical image analysis project like this takes a whole lot longer than 2 hours.)

@CrisLuengo It's a trope. https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/d6c0gy/why_i_stopped_posting_to_stackoverflow/ . I'm not arguing that it's not helpful in some cases. In this case, you came in, misread my post, made a bunch of assumptions, and implied that I was doing something bizarre. Maybe that's not what you intended but it's how it came across to me, and I would think most people would read it the same way. If I'm wrong and I'm the one misinterpreting, sorry

these pictures are on the edge of decipherable. we meatbags can do it because we have decades of context. specifically, your camera picture doesn't match either template exactly, and the two templates are even different to each other in terms of quality/preprocessing. you could run this task against some AI web service, like openai or anthropic. or use some "mechanical turk" type of service, but I doubt they still exist.

That's interesting, thanks. I should have made this more clear in my post but I'm also interested in the CV approach out of intellectual curiosity. Aside from having giant buildings full of GPUs, what's openAI doing that I can't replicate in openCV or some other package? We know chatgpt can do this, so my intuition is that I should be able to do some very small version of that locally, or more efficiently do some ML that doesn't bother with an LLM. But when I tried openCV FLANN matching, which as I understand it is ML, I found that that didn't work, either. Is it the scale of my compute?

what are openai and anthropic and other AI companies doing? enormous models that you can't even run on consumer hardware, trained on the entire internet. one cannot just replicate a trillion dollar industry over a weekend. that type of AI, at the scale it's done, is qualitatively utterly different from what you can hope to achieve. feature descriptors and matching isn't even neural networks. no it's not the scale of your computer. it's the type of problem and the type of solutions and you seem to vastly underestimate the problem. just use an API webservice to solve this for you.
